# class visualization maps

Tags: python

I am using model inferencing, where I am doing image classification tasks. I have a custom model which is being used for the classification. What I am trying to do is to run class activation maps, so I can visualize the activation maps for the image being classified for on an already trained model. For some reason, I can't find a tutorial.  However, there isn't a clear explanation on how to perform the layers check for the inputs and the data. I currently have this example:

I am using the code from this author in Google Colab:

Additionally, I have the following code:

I am honestly puzzled on how to access the layers to check for the , given that a model uses tensors, I'd like to know how can i use the libraries to use grad-cam, instead of keras/tensorflow models?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the converted Grad-Cam TFLite model with Netron (https://netron.app/), you can find out the input/output specification of the given model.

Or you can find the input/output specification through the following methods as well:

```
# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
```

After finding out the input/output specifications, you can run the model with the interpreter

```
# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

I would recommend reading the following document as well.
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python